# Prolog (SWI): string interpolation

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, string-interpolation

Is there a predicate available through the SWI-Prolog library that provides a mechanism for interpolating into strings?

What I have in mind would work as follows:

```
string(hello, %s, David)
```

However, I'm not sure if concatenation makes the desired functionality unnecessary.

```
write("hello",string(david)). % possibly inaccurate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found an answer in the documentation, but I'll leave my question up for others.
[SWI's formatted write](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=format) provides the functionality I need.

```
?- swritef(S, '%15L%w', ['Hello', 'World']).
S = "Hello          World"
```

Please feel free to comment if a better approach is possible or if I overlooked an implementation detail.

Comment: As the documentation you linked to says, the `writef` family of predicates is **deprecated**. Use `format/2` and `format/3` instead!